# SOAP xml response issue in iphone programming

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, soap, nsxmlparser

I new to iPhone and SOAP XML request.I am using SOAP web service to get response from server.I am getting following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<AuthenticateResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<AuthenticateResult>
&lt;DocumentElement&gt;
&lt;Status&gt;
&lt;EMAIL&gt;True&lt;/EMAIL&gt;
&lt;PASSWORD&gt;true&lt;/PASSWORD&gt;
&lt;/Status&gt;
&lt;/DocumentElement&gt;
</AuthenticateResult>
</AuthenticateResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

in response not getting opening and closing tag.thats why in parsing its read as string and I am unable to get values of EMAIL and PASSWORD.I am using NSXMLParser to parse response.Is there any way for convert??
Please help me ,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [class](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m) that lets you encode/decode HTML entities. Usage is very simple, just include it in your class. It provides the following methods:

```
- (NSString *)stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText;
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;
```

So you can do something like:

```
NSString *convertedString = [responseString stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];
```

Comment: Thanks Nikos M., Now I am getting proper HTML tags but in NSXMLParser we have to send NSData not NSString.how i can send this NSString to NSXMLParser??

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You can convert any NSString to NSData then pass to NSXMLParser.

Comment: Thanks,I did the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert NSString to NSData using:

```
NSData* data = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Yes, I did the same, Thanks :)